# Compass: generate Sprites, plus width / height on each images in the sprite

Tags: css, css-sprites, compass-sass, sass

I'm using Compass (a CSS Framework) to generate sprite images.
It work, but compass generate only a background-position for each image.

Is it possible to get also the width and the height for each image in the sprite?

This is my code:

```
@import "ico/*.png";
@include all-ico-sprites;
```

The generated code:

```
.ico-sprite, .ico-bag-blue, .ico-bag-black {
  background: url('../images/ico-s78b1a1919b.png') no-repeat;
}

.ico-bag-blue {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.ico-bag-black {
  background-position: 0 -24px;
}
```

And the code i would like to have:

```
.ico-sprite, .ico-bag-blue, .ico-bag-black {
  background: url('../images/ico-s78b1a1919b.png') no-repeat;
}

.ico-bag-blue {
  background-position: 0 0;
  width:40px;
  height:24px;
}

.ico-bag-black {
  background-position: 0 -24px;
  width:44px;
  height:30px;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This works:

```
@include all-<map>-sprites(true);
```

But you may want to consider the documented way of using configuration variables:
http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/

You just specify the config variable before the import.  In your case:

```
$ico-sprite-dimensions: true;
@import "ico/*png".
@include all-ico-sprites;
```

Sending `true` to the all include works, but as it's undocumented, it would seem that configuration variables are the preferred method.

Aside from dimensions these are the other configuration variables available:

```
$<map>-spacing           // space in px around the sprites
$<map>-repeat            // whether to repeat the sprite bg
$<map>-position          // the x position of the sprite on the map
$<map>-sprite-base-class // the base class (default ".<map>-sprite")
$<map>-clean-up          // whether to delete old image maps
$<map>-<sprite>-spacing  // spacing, for individual sprites
$<map>-<sprite>-repeat   // repeat, for individual sprites
$<map>-<sprite>-position // position, for individual sprites
```

Comment: No matter what I pass base-class, it always throws an error.  This config option seems broken these days.

Comment: Others such as '-layout' also exist now -- see [the latest source](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/lib/compass/sprite_importer/content.erb)

Comment: Just to make it clear, the order reflects in the result. @import "ico/*png" should come after the $<map>-property

Comment: Is there any way to set the defaults for these globally? A `$sprite-dimensions: true;` would be very useful.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder looking at [the source](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/lib/compass/sprite_importer/content.erb) it does not appear so.

Comment: @numbers1311407 That was my assumption, but glad to have a Ruby person confirm. I submitted an [issue on Github](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1702) to request this.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution.
Just pass true as the second argument :

```
@include all-ico-sprites(true);
```

Quite simply.