# SASS/Compass: Sprite images dimension (width, height)

Tags: sass, compass-sass, css-sprites

I have a bunch of images that have different dimensions. Compass is great with compiling all the files into a single sprite, generating classes from their filenames and applying the background-position to them.

Is it possible to have Compass also apply width and height properties to those generated classes?

```
$iconsWithDifferentDimensions-layout: smart;
@import "iconsWithDifferentDimensions/*.png";
@include all-iconsWithDifferentDimensions-sprites;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Set this magic variable before your @import line:

```
$iconsWithDifferentDimensions-sprite-dimensions: true;
```

And Compass will include the width and height of each icon in the sprite.

Comment: This answer has more insight to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7139117/1001109